# Would the Continuous Limit Theorem still work if we change "uniform convergence" to "pointwise convergence"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

In other words, does the conclusion still follow?

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions defined on $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

I know that in the case of uniform convergence, it works because we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that works $\forall x \in A$

All I need to disprove it is a counterexample, like

$f_n(x) = \dfrac{nx}{1+x^2}$, with a functional limit of

$\dfrac{nx}{1+nx^2} \cdot \dfrac{1/n}{1/n}=\dfrac{x}{\dfrac{1}{n}+x^2}$, as $n \rightarrow 0$, it reduces to $\dfrac{1}{x}$
Obviously, on the interval $(0,1)$ it is not uniform convergent because

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|\dfrac{1}{x+nx^3}|<\epsilon$ means that $\dfrac{1-\epsilon x}{\epsilon x^3}\geq N$, where $N$ depends on $x$.

So, I'm on the right track here?

Comment: The functions $x^n$ converge pointwise on $[0,1]$ to a discontinuous function.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pick a non-continuous function that you can converge to pointwise with continuous functions and you'll have your counterexample.

May I suggest a step function that has a converging sequence of pointwise linear functions?  You can not only arrange for pointwise convergence, but for convergence within a finite number of terms for any given point!